# Custom Tkinter OptionMenu not shown

Tags: tkinter, optionmenu, customtkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

Something is wrong with my CustomTkinter application, everything dissapears and if i remove this code it works but without my option menu. Can somebody say where i made a mistake?

```
choices = set()
for entry in df1["Cuisines"]:
    choices.update([cuisine.strip() for cuisine in entry.split(",")])
cuisine_choice = tk.StringVar()
optionmenu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(choice_window, cuisine_choice, *choices)
optionmenu.pack()
cuisine_choice.set("North Indian")
```

I need this option menu to be shown in my tkinter app

Answer (score 0):

Note that the arguments required for `CTkOptionMenu(...)` is not the same as tkinter `OptionMenu(...)`, the line `optionmenu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(choice_window, cuisine_choice, *choices)` should raise exception.

Use below instead:

```
optionmenu = ctk.CTkOptionMenu(choice_window, variable=cuisine_choice, values=list(choices))
```

See the official document on [CTkOptionMenu](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/optionmenu).